# Keyboard layout Issue in Word 2003-2007 entering accent in Greek Keyboard

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-layout, pdf-reader, addons

The problem occurs when I try to enter accent (tonos) in MS WORD 2003 (SP3) with a Greek keyboard layout,

When this happens I can't change the input language or the direction 
(neither the 
`Alt+Shift` nor `Ctrl+Shift`
 key combinations work).
By switching to the Greek language the keyboard will not enter Greek characters unless I press the SHIFT key or press a random key. 
Then I can normally type Greek characters until I try to enter a vowel with an accent.
 
When I press the `;` key (next to `L`) the language change to English and the keyboard stops again and I have to press `SHIFT` again to type greek characters.
 
Furthermore, no characters (vowels) with accents are entered.

The desktop PC used is a brand new HP PC with Windows 7 x64 in Greek language.

P.s:
 The issue is related to MS WORD and doesn't occur in any other Application.
     I tried to installed WORD 2007 but the problem remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by using the template support.dot (pre-installed with Office 2003) 

It was a great help as it guided towards the solution, which was caused by a bad COM Add-In (PDF Complete)

It seems that PDF complete was pre-installed with the HP Windows 7 factory installation.

The issue ceased to exist as soon as the application was Removed/Uninstall from
 `Control Panel`>`Programs and Features`>`PDF Complete`